# What are the massive stables at Megeto?

Tags: solomon

I've listened to [this lecture](https://youtu.be/nmemVWzL3bw?t=508) and I can't, however hard I try, decode the sentence:

> Solomon ignored God's wisdom and later in life, he literally broke every one of them except for being a foreigner. He married 700 women. Not smart. Had 300 concubines. He owned enough horses to fill all of the *massive stables at Mageto* that you can see in Israel today.

Does anyone know about a place in Israel sounding like *stables at Magedo*?

Comment: Please [edit] this to fix all your typos.

Comment: What does destroying all the gods have to do with the stables? Please quote whatever it is you're talking about.

Comment: According to the Bible story, Solomon had 700 wives, not 7,000. See [1 Kings 11:1-3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Kings+11%3A1-3&version=NIV). Did the lecture really say 7,000? If so, it is mistaken.

Comment: @DickHarfield I thought it have been good with the Mageto version because whoever would google this in future would find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The speaker would be talking about [Megiddo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Megiddo). Archaeologist have found stables which could hold perhaps up to 500 horses. Although some had said that the stables dated from the time of Solomon, [Wikipedia says that most now think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tel_Megiddo#Archaeological_features) they are from 150 years later, the time of Ahab.

Comment: Thank you! Destroying all the gods doesn't have anything to do with the stables of Megiddo. But I just don't understand it as well.

Comment: @Probably Then please ask that as a separate question.

Comment: I've [asked](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54306/which-gods-did-salamon-destroye), thanks

Comment: Adding to this answer: it is now believed they were not stables, but warehouses.